# Ubuntu boot option keeps coming back after being deleted

Tags: boot, bios, clone

I cloned a windows drive to a dell laptop that was using Ubuntu but it keeps trying to boot to Ubuntu. Went into bios and deleted all Ubuntu boot options but when I go back into bios after reboot they all come back. Tried going into bios with no drive installed and it still has Ubuntu boot options. Restored bios to factory default and reset everything but it won't go away. There has to be some setting in bios that is forcing the system to use Linux but I can't see anything.

Comment: So your laptop is booting to GRUB then? And there are no windows options showing in the GRUB menu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)